# Why isn't Xcode text search returning results from my Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using a large 3rd party framework installed via Cocoapods.  I'm trying to determine where it is making use of a certain class.  So I did a text search in Xcode for the specific class name, and it won't return any results for any code that is a part of a Cocoapod.  I have set it to search the entire workspace, including the Pods project.

Does anyone know why this is, and is there a way to make it search the Pods as well?

Comment: what type of search you used , for e.g `match` , `containing` , `startswidth`, `endswidth`

Comment: i'm using containing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure it says "In Workspace" and that it is not blue (because then, you can change the scope of your search and can not see the search results)

Comment: that didn't work.  Also your link to the image is broken (503 error)